# Under given conditions, is the probability of collision between two balls in a box greater than zero? How to prove it?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, particle-physics

This is a question I've been thinking about lately.Maybe not very rigorous.

In a finite space, there's a finite number of, let's say, a cubic meter, and there's a million rigid bodies in one cubic micron. These balls are suspended in the air, all moving randomly, with gaps between them, but they can collide. The balls then exist for an average of one second, but randomly appear elsewhere as soon as they disappear, leaving the total number of balls unchanged. Excuse me, is the collision probability of every two balls greater than 0? How to calculate?

PS：Thanks to the discussion of net friend I limit it here, no space overlap between the ball and the ball.

I hope my English expression will not cause ambiguity

Comment: I think that more information is needed in order to provide an expression for the probability. If no restrictions are given, the balls could also superpose in space. I would say that as they move randomly it does not matter, in the long run,  if they disappear and appear or they don't

Comment: However, if their density probability function is the same, there is a not null probability of collision (related to the product of those densities in case of no cross correlation)

Comment: It seems like you're asking about how much time it would take to have each pair of balls be likely to hit each other? Is my reading correct?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I think you're getting it wrong. What I want to ask is not the time of the collision, but whether each ball is likely to collide with each other. What is the probability of two balls hitting each other with this property?